# coefficients of logistic regression model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) to build a logistic regression model using TensorFlow. I have a simple question: How can I print the model's coefficients like `.coef_` in `sklearn`?

Piece of code after preprocessing and before training the model:

```
model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[
  gender, native_country, education, occupation, workclass, marital_status, race,
  age_buckets, education_x_occupation, age_buckets_x_education_x_occupation],
  model_dir=model_dir)
m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

and here is the results of `ls -l` on `model_dir`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff       305 Jul 17 13:29 checkpoint
drwxr-xr-x  3 builder  staff       102 Jul 17 13:29 eval
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff  39038807 Jul 17 13:29 events.out.tfevents.1500323287.builder-MBP.ikuni.com
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff  32604586 Jul 17 13:28 graph.pbtxt
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff  12567520 Jul 17 13:28 model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff      3240 Jul 17 13:28 model.ckpt-1.index
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff   9830014 Jul 17 13:28 model.ckpt-1.meta
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff  12567520 Jul 17 13:29 model.ckpt-200.data-00000-of-00001
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff      3240 Jul 17 13:29 model.ckpt-200.index
-rw-r--r--  1 builder  staff   9830014 Jul 17 13:29 model.ckpt-200.meta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the two methods: `get_variable_names()` to get the variables in the model and  then use `get_variable_value()` to get the  coefficients of a particular variable of the trained model.